# initialize a class by string variable in c#?

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, instance

is it possible to initialize a class by a string variable? I have code in PHP.

```
<?php
  $classname = "test";

  $oTest = new $classname();

  class test{
  }
?>
```

how do I do this in c#?

Comment: I think JaredPar answers your question, however why do you need this? What are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className))
```

The problem, however, is that C# 3.0 is a statically typed language. You can't just call random methods on the returned object. You can have the classes you might instantiate implement some common interface and cast the result of the above expression to the interface or manually use reflection to call methods on the returned object.

Comment: Seeing the answer helped me understand the question. +1

Comment: What do you mean by "C#, as of Version 3.0 is a statically typed language". That suggests it only recently became a statically typed language. It always has been. In C# 4.0 there is the new dynamic keyword which means that C# will get some aspects of dynamic languages if desired.

Comment: Colin: I might have worded it ambiguously. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Activator.CreateInstance method to achieve a *similar* result.  But you will have to provide the assembly name in addition to the fully qualified name of the type

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance("SomeAssemblyName","Some.Full.Type.Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Activator.CreateInstance. The documentation for the various overloads is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx