# c# string to class from which I can call functions

Tags: c#, activator, createinstance

on [initialize a class by string variable in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252371/initialize-a-class-by-string-variable-in-c) I already found out how to create an class using a string

so what I already have is:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("project.start");
var class = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

what I want to do is call a function on this class for example:

```
class.foo();
```

is this possible? and if it is how?

Answer (score 4):

```
Type yourType = Type.GetType("project.start");
object yourObject = Activator.CreateInstance(yourType);

object result = yourType.GetMethod("foo")
                        .Invoke(yourObject, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume that the class implements an interface or base class that exposes a Foo method, then cast the class as appropriate.

```
public interface IFoo
{
   void Foo();
}
```

then in your calling code you can do:

```
var yourType = Type.GetType("project.start");
var yourObject = (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(yourType);

yourType.Foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but you will have to use reflection or have `class` be cast as the proper type at runtime..

Reflection Example:

```
type.GetMethod("foo").Invoke(class, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Activator.CreateInstance` returns a type of `object`.  If you know the type at compile time, you can use the generic CreateInstance.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("project.start");
var class = Activator.CreateInstance<project.start>(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("foo");
object result  = methodInfo.Invoke(class,null);
```

The second argument to the Invoke method are the method parameters.