# convert class string to class

Tags: c#, class

I have the code below in my ASP.NET app, I would like to convert `converterName` variable to
Class and pass it to `FillRequest<T>` method.
Is it possible?

```
var converterName = HttpContext.Current.Items["ConverterName"] as string;
FillRequest<Web2ImageEntity>(Request.Params);
```

Alternatively I could do

```
    var converterName = HttpContext.Current.Items["ConverterName"] as string;

if (converterName == "Web2ImageEntity")
    FillRequest<Web2ImageEntity>(Request.Params);
```

but I have about 20 entity classes and I would like to find a way to write code as short as possible.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252371/initialize-a-class-by-string-variable-in-c

Comment: No, your posted thread do not answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

That would not be possible as the generic type needs to be specified at the compile time.
What you can do is change the FillRequest method to be something like below and then use reflection to do the desired task

```
FillRequest(string[] params,Type converter)
{
  //Create object from converter type and call the req method
}
```

Or make the FillRequest take a Interface

```
FillRequest(string[] params, IConverter c)
{
 //call c methods to convert
}
```

Calling this would be something like:

```
   var type = Type.GetType(converterName);
   FillRequest(Request.Params,(IConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```

Comment: Every *Entity class has its own collection of properties. I do not understand how usage of Interface could help in this situation.

Comment: Your code looks like you are passing some converter type name. If it is an entity object then the first option of using reflection inside FillRequest would do the job

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at Activator.CreateInstance():

```
        var converterName = HttpContext.Current.Items["ConverterName"] as string;

        var type = Type.GetType(converterName);
        var yourObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Be aware that the type must have a public parameterless constructor.  Here is a link to the MSDN documentation; there are a bunch of overloads which might be useful to you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

UPDATE: If you must pass the object to a method with a generic type, then you will run into problems because the type is not known at compile time.  In that case, I would consider having all of your converters implement a common interface, something like this:

```
var converterName = HttpContext.Current.Items["ConverterName"] as string;

var type = Type.GetType(converterName);
var yourObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IMyConverter;
if (yourObject != null)
    FillRequest<IMyConverter>(yourObject);
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried to use your suggested code but I do not find how to pass class type as T to FillRequest<T>. Could you show how to do that?

Comment: If your FillRequest method has a generic type parameter, then this will not be possible.  In that case, I would consider having all of your converters implement a common interface and call FillRequest<IMyConverterInterface>(...)?

Answer (score 1):

I found code idea [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32478552/pass-regular-type-to-generic-method.aspx). Peter Moris pointed that he took code from Jon Skeets book, so if it will be useful - high five to Jon :)

create method:

```
public void DoFillRequest(Type type, string[] params)
{
   MethodInfo methodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("FillRequest");
   MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[]{ type });
   genericMethodInfo.Invoke(this, new object[]{ params });
}
```

and now call it:

```
var type = Type.GetType(converterName);
DoFillRequest(type, Request.Params);
```