# GetType When Type Is Provided As A String

Tags: reflection, gettype

I understand that C# is a staticly typed language and I already read the answers to this SO posting:
[initialize a class by string variable in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252371/initialize-a-class-by-string-variable-in-c)

My question is a bit different, however. I'm working with a T4 template that provides me with the name of a class as a string parameter. I would give the template code here but what's important is that the type is in a string, so it's the same as having this statement in any C# module:

```
string s = "MyNamespace.Customer.Model";
```

Using that string, I need to get the type into a Type variable. Normally, I would use this code when I have access to the actual type:

```
Type typeModel = typeof(MyNamespace.Customer.Model);
```

How would I be able to obtain the Type given a string? In other words, my code would ideally look something like this (I know this doesn't work because "s" is a string):

```
Type typeModel = typeof(s);
```

(I do know what assembly the type is in, by the way, so I can use that information; also, the assembly containing the Type in question is referenced by the template, for what that's worth...)

Note: I do not want to create an object instance of the Type so please don't suggest a solution that requires using Activator.CreateInstance unless that's the only solution...

Thank you for any ideas you can provide.

Comment: Is the range of possible types known in advance?

Comment: No, unfortunately. This is code that will go into one of Microsoft's supplied MVC scaffold templates. The idea is that you can scaffold any model in your project--so, no, I have no idea what model types can be presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`Type.GetType(string typeName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does what you want, but if you only provide the [`FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (namespace and name) of the type, it will only resolve types from the current assembly or mscorlib.

You would need to supply an [`AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to resolve types outside the current assembly. The problem of course is that multiple assemblies can contain different types with the same name and namespace (thanks Steven Liekens):

```
string aqn = Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(assemblyName, namespaceAndNameOfType);
Type t = Type.GetType(aqn);
```

If you don't know the assembly beforehand, you could deal with this by:

- Loading all assemblies from the current [`AppDomain.BaseDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or
- Using [`AppDomain.GetAssemblies()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the currently loaded assemblies

And then iterating over each assembly's [`GetTypes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Comment: It's looking like you can use the static `Assembly.CreateQualifiedName()` to improve your answer.

Comment: @StevenLiekens I did not know that method existed, thank you!

Comment: I'm going to try the Assembly.CreateQualifiedName() tomorrow and I'll let you know what I discover.

Comment: The Assembly.CreateQualifiedName function didn't work for me. It returns an aqn, but when I execute Type.GetType(aqn) I get this error: 
"The given assembly name or codebase was invalid."

Upon further reading, CreateQualifiedName take two arguments, the assembly name and the type name (as strings). The assembly name should be a "FullTypeName". That led me to the AssemblyName Class. I tried passing the FullTypeName that I got from .Net Reflector, but I received the same error message. I can't intuit the full-type-name anyway from what's passed in so I will need a different solution...

Comment: In the end, you need to at least supply `"Namespace.Typename, AssemblyName"`. If the assembly is signed, you'll need to include additional information to resolve the assembly.

Comment: Yes, I did provide the Namespace.Typename ("MyNamespace.Customer.Model") as well as the full (verified) path to the .DLL assembly on my system.

Comment: I have another idea to solve this problem but it's a template question. I posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916648/converting-string-parameter-in-t4-template-to-literal-text

Comment: @Jazimov You should not supply the _filename_ but the _assembly name_. Typically it's the file name without extension, but you can verify that using Reflector.

Comment: OK, I used ILSpy and passed this as the assembly name argument:
"MyApp.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
That is what the full assembly name is, according to the reflection tool. Guess what? That worked! :) For other, the full function looks like:
Assembly.CreateQualifiedName("MyApp.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","MyApp.Models.Customer");
Now I'm going to play with dropping off the Culture and PublicKeyToken values to see if things will still work--and possibly even the version, as only one version should ever exist. THANK YOU!