# How to Instantiate a Interface or class from given string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.reflection

this is the function I call

```
this.ExecuteSQLProcedure("sp_GenerateInterface", new object[] { TableName });
```

Result of above function and is stored in string variable

```
string tableInterface  = 

Public Class UserMaster
{
     Guid UserId { get; set; }
     string UserName { get; set; }
     Guid RoleId { get; set; }
     string FirstName { get; set; }
     string LastName { get; set; }
     Guid AddressId { get; set; }
     long ContactNumber { get; set; }
     string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
     bool? IsActive { get; set; }
     Guid? EntryBy { get; set; }
     DateTime? EntryDate { get; set; }
     Guid? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
     DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
     Guid? DeletedBy { get; set; }
     DateTime? DeletedDate { get; set; }
     string Email { get; set; }
     bool fnCheckContactNumberExists( long ContactNumber );
     bool fnCheckEmailExists( string Email );
     bool fnCheckUserExistsorNot( string LoginCredential );
     bool fnCheckUserNameAvailable( string UserName );
     bool fnCheckUserNameExists( string UserName );
     bool fnCheckUserStatus( string LoginCredntial );
     string fnGenerateFrenchiseNumber( );
     string fnGetFirstLastName( string LoginCredential );
     Guid fnGetUserId( string LoginCredential );
     void sp_AuthenticateLogin( string LoginCredential,  out string Message,  out string MessageType,  string Password );
     void sp_CreateUser( string City,  long ContactNumber,  string Email,  string FirstName,  string HouseNo,  string LandMark,  string Lane,  string LastName,  string LoginCredential,  out string Message,  out string MessageType,  string Password,  string Street,  string UserName );
}
```

Now I want to instantiate this Class so that I can use it anywhere

Comment: Welcome to [so], I think you can have a lot of result for instantiate an object from a string (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252371/initialize-a-class-by-string-variable-in-c) ).  But instantiate an interface... maybe you should try to search the [so] and google, if still can't get your result, you can ask here again.

Comment: You mean the stored procedure returns the C# representation of interface and you want to use that interface? Am I getting it right?

Comment: yes Chetan Ranpariya, My stored procedure returns the c# representation of Class and i want to use that class. First it was Interface so that i can implement or inherit an interface, now I converted to an Class

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialize interface. You need to implement class from this interface.

```
class UserMaster : IUserMaster
 {
 //implementation of methods.
 }
what inmlements all the metods.
```

and you need to make converter, to be able assign values to this class. 
Be cause you want to have class with properties to equal with string?

Comment: Suppose the output is in class form

Comment: can you provide an example of this string tableInterface ?

Comment: above written is the output of the table related functions and stored procedures with Columns as properties. This output is in a class form